# Pine Script: Unique ID for strategy.entry function

Tags: scripting, pine-script, trading, forex

I want to generate unique ID for PineScript's strategy.entry function:

```
unique_id = tostring(bar_index)
strategy.entry(unique_id, ...)
```

The problem here is that strategy.entry only takes ID parameter of type **const string**, whereas any solution I tried gives either **series[string]** or **string**.
Is there any way to make it work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't be done. Don't ask the same question in multiple forums. You risk getting different volunteers helping you concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

```
id = "Two candle reversal " + tostring(time("") / 100000)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It's pretty readable in what it's trying to achieve without being verbose,  simplicity should not be discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
strategy("Unique_Id")

whprng(Seed) => // Wichmann–Hill Pseudo-Random Number Generator
    var germinate = Seed * hlc3 * timenow
    float s1 = na, s1 := 171.0 * nz(s1[1], germinate) % 30269.0
    float s2 = na, s2 := 172.0 * nz(s2[1], s1 * Seed) % 30307.0
    float s3 = na, s3 := 170.0 * nz(s3[1], s2 * Seed) % 30323.0
    (s1 / 30269.0 + s2 / 30307.0 + s3 / 30323.0) % 1.0

idLength = 5
rndIndex = 0
alpha = array.from('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')

isUnique = false
rstring = ""
while isUnique == false
    rstring := ""
    isUnique := true
    for i = 0 to idLength
        rndIndex := math.floor(whprng(23+i) * array.size(alpha))
        rstring := rstring + array.get(alpha, rndIndex)
        alert("Routine 1")
        
    entryId = ''

    // check open orders for uniqueness
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        entryId := strategy.opentrades.entry_id(tradeNo)
        if(entryId == rstring)
            isUnique := false
            break

    // check closed orders for uniqueness
    if(isUnique == true)
        for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
            entryId := strategy.closedtrades.entry_id(tradeNo)
            if(entryId == rstring)
                isUnique := false
                break
// end while

alert("Unique ID = " + rstring)
const someId = rstring
```